# Filter out SSIS errors

Tags: ssis

The way SSIS generates errors are bit weird. Error detail contains lots of unnecessary data such as "pipeline stopped executing...", "the error is fatal..","The user requested a shutdown..." and on... This is not very user friendly for a end user. So I was wondering on is there any way where we can log/send specific errors only?
In my case where I upload data from csv file to sql table for data conversion error SSIS sends me 20 lines of error log and I need to remove all unnecessary stuff. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since standard logging in SSIS does produce an overwhelming amount of junky, you could rely on using reports in SSRS that filter down some of this data.  If you know you don't care about messages that contain specific phrases, then you could suppress them in your query with a NOT LIKE statement.  Alternatively, you could setup a process to purge the records from the sysdtslog table if you absolutely know you never want them in your database.  Neither are great solutions, but they are easy to implement without having to write a custom logging solution.

**REVISION**

You can log custom errors with [event handlers](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/06/11/SSIS_3A00_-Custom-Logging-Using-Event-Handlers.aspx).  There's even an article on how to implement [custom logging with custom tasks](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/SSIS_Custom_Logging_Task_for_Event_Handlers.aspx) that literally takes the original article and goes a step further.  Both of them are useful for understanding how you could control how error messages are logged and the content of the messages.

Comment: ummm...I can give try for your solutions but I am looking for something like I can send error messages in very user friendly way like..The 'Data conversion' or 'ABC' type of error occurred at row no.32 and column 'XYZ' in input file.

Comment: You could log specific errors through event handlers.  I'll revise my answer to include a link to a good article on how to accomplish this goal.

Comment: Thanks! I will try these solutions.